# How can I get a list of all words which overflow to margin

Tags: margins, hyphenation, overflow

I made a document and when I compile it, I get in the final pdf multiple words which overflow to margin, without hyphenation.

I plan to manually set their hyphenation with the command `\hyphenation{wor-ds to hyph-en}` but before I need the list of all words which overflow.

For example, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a6paper,8.5pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=10mm, left=5mm, right=10mm, showframe,
foot=5mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

gain de gout pour la rationalité qu’à pris pied ce néo-loxitanisme

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, coonsectetur adipiscing mais Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, no-dignissimmmmm sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Craselementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. no-Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.


\end{document}
```

I get the following rendering:

[image]

And the goal is to get a list like this:

```
no-loxitasime no-dignissimmmmm no-Pellentesque
```

So, is there an automatic way to get a list?

Comment: The `.log` should have lines about "Overfull hbox", along with how much it juts into the margin.  They will point you toward the line in the source code.  I think the `draft` option for the article class will highlight those lines as well.  But I'm not sure about extbook, nor about actually getting those words.

Comment: the log will show all the overfull lines you can use `\setboxbreadth\maxdimen` to make sure it shows the full box, but note that a full list is not that useful, as after you change the hyphenation for the first word that was over-full, linebreaking for the whole paragraph will change and a potentially different set of words will be considered for hyphenation, so it needs to be an iterative process.

Comment: note that tex does not hyphenate explictly hyphenated words so you know in advance that it can not break any of the three words shown in the image, you do not need to use tex at all to find those, just search for hyphenated words in the source.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you meant `\showboxbreadth\maxdimen` (typo)

Comment: I find the bash solution with the command `pcregrep -M 'Overfull.*\n.*\n.*' <process name>.log | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n[^(Overfull)]//g' | sed "s/.* \(.*\)/\1/" ` but it still a little bit hacky…